# Typescript - Error while compiling a .ts file in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm getting the below error, while I try to compile a `.ts` file from the Visual Studio Code IDE. (Using <kbd>Ctrl+</kbd><kbd>Shift+</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>)

**Problem matcher {0} can't be resolved. The matcher will be ignoredThe filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

Here is my `tasks.json`,

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

Can someone help me what could be the issue here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have not configured a task runner for transpiling Typescript.

On VS Code, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type "Configure Task Runner", press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select it. Select "Typescript.json" from the options.

Save all and it should work.

The complete reference on configuring Typescript can be found here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

Comment: The tasks.json created by following the steps I described above contain more keys that the one you showed on your question.

Comment: {
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}